# Is it possible to split a circle into 9 sections of equal area using 4 secant lines?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to split a circle into 9 sections with equal area using 4 secant lines?

Why or why not?

What is an example solution, if any?

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220161/divide-circle-into-9-pieces-of-equal-area

Comment: Yes, it's possible but the solution will most likely be numerical due to the nature of the resulting equation

Comment: You may create equations for the two unknowns and than solve for them. On it face, it seems that you can do it by the use of two sets of two perpendicular lines. May be there are more than one solution.

Comment: @Moti how would you be able to do so?

Comment: The two sets of lines will create a square in the middle and 2 types of shapes, 4 each, between it and the square and the circle line. two unknowns are the square side and the segments from the vertices to the circle. you have 3 equations and 2 unknown that will allow you to evaluate if it is possible. Add an unknown of and angle between the pair (not perpendicular) and now you have 3 equations and 3 unknown to solve.

Comment: I assume you want straight lines. If you go for the square at the center Moti just described, then you know it's size has to be $\frac19$ the area of the circle. Use the unit circle without loss of generality, and a square of edge length $\frac13\sqrt\pi$ at the origin. If you extend its edges, do you get $\frac19\pi$ area for the other shapes as well? I would *guess* not. In that case the square in the center approach is dead. I would be surprised if a less symmetric approach were to work any better. I would *guess* this is altogether impossible.

Comment: Note that in [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220161/35416) which NoChance cited above, I used circles not straight lines which gave me the circle radius / curvature as another degree of freedom. I needed that freedom to allow for a solution, there was no freedom in the solution to make the arcs straight. On the other hand I started by fixing the arrangement of tiles and their congruences, so theoretically you could come up with a different (less symmetric?) arrangement using straight lines. I doubt that, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!